# Need help modifying my python code so that it displays a message when a dice roll is the same as the previous iteration within a for loop?

Tags: python

So, in my python class, I am making a program that asks how many dice you want to roll and then rolls a die (via random integer generator) that amount of times; it then adds and prints the total while also giving a message if one roll has the same value as a previous roll. Everything seems to be working; I just can't figure out how I can make the code detect when I've had the same number in a row and how to display a message for that. The prompt for the lab suggests creating a variable that keeps track of the previous roll, but I'm honestly not sure how to do that either. Here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    num_dice = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll? '))
    while num_dice > 12 or num_dice < 3:
        print('Sorry, the number of dice must be between 3 and 12')
        num_dice = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll? '))
    roll_dice(num_dice)



def roll_dice(num_dice):
    import random
    rolls = 0
    for dice in range(1, num_dice + 1):
        print(f'Dice {dice}: {(rolls2 := random.randint(1, 6))}')
        rolls += rolls2
    print(f'Total: {rolls}')



main()
```

This is what the output is supposed to look like:

```
How many dice do you want to roll? 8
Dice 1: 1
Dice 2: 3
Dice 3: 3 -> On a roll!
Dice 4: 3 -> On a roll!
Dice 5: 6
Dice 6: 4
Dice 7: 6
Dice 8: 3
Total: 29
```

I don't remember going over this in class, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

simply save every roll on a list and match latest roll to previous roll using simple logic `a[dice]==a[dice-1]:`

**Code:**

```
def main():
    num_dice = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll? '))
    while num_dice > 12 or num_dice < 3:
        print('Sorry, the number of dice must be between 3 and 12')
        num_dice = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll? '))
    roll_dice(num_dice)



def roll_dice(num_dice):
    import random
    rolls = 0
    a=[0,]
    for dice in range(1, num_dice + 1):
        {rolls2 := random.randint(1, 6)}
        a.append(rolls2)
        if a[dice]==a[dice-1]:
             print(f'Dice {dice}: {rolls2}---> on a roll')
        else:
             print(f'Dice {dice}: {rolls2}')
        rolls += rolls2
    print(f'Total: {rolls}')


main()
```

**Output:**

```
How many dice would you like to roll? 8
Dice 1: 4
Dice 2: 4---> on a roll
Dice 3: 3
Dice 4: 5
Dice 5: 1
Dice 6: 3
Dice 7: 3---> on a roll
Dice 8: 2
Total: 25
```

**WITHOUT USING LIST**

```
def main():
    num_dice = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll? '))
    while num_dice > 12 or num_dice < 3:
        print('Sorry, the number of dice must be between 3 and 12')
        num_dice = int(input('How many dice would you like to roll? '))
    roll_dice(num_dice)



def roll_dice(num_dice):
    import random
    rolls = 0
    rolls1 =0
    for dice in range(1, num_dice + 1):
        {rolls2 := random.randint(1, 6)}
        if rolls1==rolls2:
             print(f'Dice {dice}: {rolls2}---> on a roll')
        else:
             print(f'Dice {dice}: {rolls2}')
        rolls1=rolls2
        rolls += rolls2
    print(f'Total: {rolls}')


main()
```

**Output:**

```
How many dice would you like to roll? 12
Dice 1: 6
Dice 2: 2
Dice 3: 6
Dice 4: 3
Dice 5: 4
Dice 6: 4---> on a roll
Dice 7: 2
Dice 8: 2---> on a roll
Dice 9: 1
Dice 10: 6
Dice 11: 5
Dice 12: 3
Total: 44
```

Comment: We haven't gone over lists yet is there any way to do it without one?

Comment: we can store into another variable whenever new values in it can check then update value, same as list but we need couple of variables and little bit logics too.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: I will try it takes some time. can I manipulate you code little bit too.

Comment: @Mehmaam you can try a deep copy of the variable to avoid re assignment. Good luck!

Comment: Take your time I appreciate any help, really. You can dissect my code if you'd like (I assume you were asking a question). I'm just really new to python, so we haven't covered lists yet in class, so if there was a way I could do it without one, it'd be awesome.

Comment: Already done. both are easy method but List is an efficient way to do that so if you clear in question we can help your more early. Now check it.  Minor changes

Comment: Awesome! it seems to be working. I seriously appreciate you, man!

Comment: i dont want to said that but if you want i dont force you but if you think it can help you then accept it or upvote, again mate its your choice and my hardworks payoff.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and seems working, please let me know.

```
def roll_dice(num_dice):
    import random
    rolls = 0
    value = []
    for dice in range(num_dice):
        rolls2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        value.append(rolls2)
        if rolls2 == value[dice-1] and dice >= 1 :
            print(f'Dice {dice+1}: {rolls2} -> On a roll!')
        else:
            print(f'Dice {dice+1}: {rolls2}')
        rolls += rolls2
    print(f'Total: {rolls}')
```

The output for 8 dices:

```
How many dice would you like to roll? 8
Dice 1: 2
Dice 2: 4
Dice 3: 4 -> On a roll!
Dice 4: 4 -> On a roll!
Dice 5: 4 -> On a roll!
Dice 6: 2
Dice 7: 2 -> On a roll!
Dice 8: 2 -> On a roll!
Total: 24
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but is there any way to do this without lists?

Comment: You need to track the previous value of the dice. You can do a dictionary as well.

Comment: So how would we go about tracking it? I'm still a beginner for the most part. I honestly don't even know where to begin.

Comment: you can do print(value) after the Total to have a look the history of the values in that list.

Comment: In any case, I think we help you enough so far. Kindly accept one of the answers and show appreciation upvoting the answers if they worked for your problem. Regards.

Comment: I can't upvote them, unfortunately. But also, I realized you actually did the code wrong. in your output, it goes die 1, die 1, die 3, die 3 when it should just go numerical order. Not sure why that's occurring.

Comment: I upvote you and also I fixed a small typo. Regards.